# How can i pass the value of my input to javascript through ID

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

So this is my code in HTML:

```html
<div><label> Control Number </label>
  <input name="get_control_num" style="text-transform:uppercase"
    class="form-control" id="sel_control_num" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Quantity </label>
  <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number"
    onchange="addInputs(this)" />
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Control Number </button>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="parent"></div>
```

and this is my code in Javascript where i used setAttribute

```js
function addInputs(pass) {
  var n = pass.value && parseInt(pass.value, 10);
  if (isNaN(n)) {
    return;
  }
  var input;
  var getCurrdata = document.getElementById("sel_control_num");
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  functionPopulate(parent);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Control No.')
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('class', 'onInput');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'get_Input_show');
    input.setAttribute('value', '*suppose to be value of ID #select_control_num*');
    document.getElementById("parent").style.padding = "5px 0px 0px 0px";
    parent.appendChild(input);
  }
}

function functionPopulate(div) {
  div.innerHTML = '';
}
```

How can i pass the value of whats inside of the `ID(#sel_control_num)` in my HTML so that if i add depending on how many quantities i put, it should display the data of that ID. I can't think of proper solution because i am new to javascript. Thanks for the help.

Comment: pretty sure you could just write `input.value = 'something'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
input.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById('sel_control_num').value);
```

Note that the `<input>` in the HTML you posted has an ID of `sel_control_num` and not `select_control_num` as your write in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
input.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById('select_control_num').value);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Another solution would be

```
input.setAttribute('value', document.querySelector('#select_control_num').value);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Also be aware that you are asking to get the value from the element with id `select_control_num` but I only see an element with id `sel_control_num` in your html so make sure those match.

Comment: Thank you sir! it actually worked. Yeah i changed it. Haha